# DP based algo for Stock maximize problem Hackerank

Tags: c++11, dynamic-programming

I need some help solving the Stock maximize problem on hackerrank the problem is at this link https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/stockmax/problem
I know there's a linear approach to solve this problem but I needed help with Dynamic Programming involving a solution of mine. It gives TLE when I submit it.
As a learner I just want to know is there any further optimization I can do to my DP based solution.
I wrote the following function to evaluate the answer

```
long myans(vector<int> prices, unordered_map<int,unordered_map<int, long>> &mp ,int st,long ns,long pr)
{
   //base
   if(st==prices.size())
   return pr;
   //dp
   if( mp[ns][st]!=0)
   return  mp[ns][st];
   //rec
   long dn=0,ss=0,bs=0;
   if(st!=prices.size()-1)
   bs=myans(prices,mp,st+1,ns+1,pr-prices[st]);
   if(ns>0)
   ss=myans(prices,mp,st+1,0,pr+ns*prices[st]);
   dn=myans(prices,mp,st+1,ns,pr);
   mp[ns][st]=max(bs,max(ss,dn));
   // mp[st+1][ns+1]=bs;
   // mp[st+1][ns]=dn;
   // mp[st+1][0]=ss;
    return mp[ns][st];
   //return  mp[make_pair(ns,prices[st])];
}
long stockmax(vector<int> prices) {
unordered_map<int,unordered_map<int, long>> mp;
   return myans(prices,mp,0,0,0);

}
```

Comment: The linear solution you say is probably the optimized DP solution,

Comment: You are passing `prices` by value, this causes a copy to be made for every recursive call. Make it a `const` reference.

Comment: @G.Sliepen i tried it , but it still shows TLE for all test cases

Comment: It would be easier to assist if the code had variable names that made sense at a glance, was better formatted, and the question included a description of the algorithm you're attempting. It's likely even a memoised recursion,  as this seems to be, results in long execution time due to the number of branches produced. Verify this by counting and logging how many iterations have happened by successful termination with increasing input size. Also look for edge cases that may result in an infinite loop.